# BPY - How to set Bone Parent?

Tags: python

I have a bone called **'Hips'**, i want to set it's parent to bone **'Root'**, how can i do this?

these are some codes i've tried but didn't work

`bpy.context.object.data.parent = C.object.data.edit_bones['Root']`
i tried to select Hips bone then run this code to set the selected bone's parent to Root, but it gave this error `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

i also tried this code `bpy.context.object.data.parent = bpy.data.armatures["Armature"].["Root"]`
no wonder it didn't work either.

i'm using Blender 2.82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I used, the following two lines of code did the job:

```
arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
arm.data.edit_bones['boneName'].parent = arm.data.edit_bones['parentBone']
```