# Blender python parent bone

Tags: python, rigging

I need to parent one bone to another using python, but when using this code it has an error that says " KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Bone" not found'",
This is the code :

```
arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
arm.data.edit_bones['Bone.001'].parent = arm.data.edit_bones['Bone']
```

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179819/bpy-how-to-set-bone-parent) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`edit_bones` are available only in edit mode. Either force blender to switch to edit mode or check if the wrong mode is active.

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
arm.data.edit_bones['Bone.001'].parent = arm.data.edit_bones['Bone']
```

Comment: thanks, nice to know that

Answer (score 1):

```
# blender ver: 2.93.3
# In object mode
import bpy

oj = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = oj      #set context.object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')            #to edit mode
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action='DESELECT')  #deselect all bone

bones = oj.data.edit_bones
bones["Bone.001"].select = True
bones["Bone"].select = True

bpy.ops.armature.parent_set(type='CONNECTED')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
#print name
print("children name: ", oj.data.bones["Bone.001"].children[0].name)
print("parent name: ", oj.data.bones["Bone"].parent.name)
```

Comment: this is works and great, but not sure if it can run in the command line. Thanks